# Getting an address IP and using a socket to connect to it

Tags: c, sockets, gethostbyname

I'm writing an HTTP client using UNIX sockets (as part of a homework assignment).  I currently have this working code to connect to a given IP Address:

```
int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
char *server_address = "127.0.0.1";
struct sockaddr_in address;
if (sockfd < 0) {
    printf("Unable to open socket\n"); 
    exit(1);
}

// Try to connect to server_address on port PORT
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_address);
address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(address)) < 0) {
    printf("Unable to connect to host\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

However, I now want to modify it so that `server_address` could also be something that is not an IP, such as "google.com".  I've been trying to figure out how to do this using `gethostbyname`, but I am having trouble.

**Will gethostbyname accept both an IP Address OR an address like "google.com" and have it work correctly?** (or should I try and run a regex on the address first and do something else if it is an IP Address)?

I have tried the following code to try to get it working with something like "google.com", but I am getting a warning `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`

```
struct hostent *host_entity = gethostbyname(server_address);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = host_entity->h_addr_list[0];
```

I know I am doing-it-wrong, but the gethostbyname documentation is atrocious.

Comment: `memcpy(&address.sin_addr, host_entity->h_addr_list[0], host_entity->h_length);`

Comment: @BrianRoach that did it!  If you wanted to write that up as an answer, I would accept it. :)

Comment: Just make sure you validate that `host_entity` is not NULL, and that `host_entity->h_addrtype` is `AF_INET`, before copying any value from `host_entity->h_addr_list` into `address.sin_addr.s_addr`. That said, `gethostbyname()` is deprecated, use `getaddrinfo()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is maybe `getaddrinfo(3)`:

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

static int
resolve(const char *host, const char *port)
{
        struct addrinfo *aires;
        struct addrinfo hints = {0};
        int s = -1;

        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_flags = 0;
#if defined AI_ADDRCONFIG
        hints.ai_flags |= AI_ADDRCONFIG;
#endif  /* AI_ADDRCONFIG */
#if defined AI_V4MAPPED
        hints.ai_flags |= AI_V4MAPPED;
#endif  /* AI_V4MAPPED */
        hints.ai_protocol = 0;

        if (getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &aires) &lt; 0) {
                goto out;
        }
        /* now try them all */
        for (const struct addrinfo *ai = aires;
             ai != NULL &&
                     ((s = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, 0)) &lt; 0 ||
                      connect(s, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen) &lt; 0);
             close(s), s = -1, ai = ai->ai_next);

out:
        freeaddrinfo(aires);
        return s;
}
```

This version gets you a socket from a host/port pair.  It also takes IP addresses for host and service strings for port.  It will, however, connect to the host in question already.